# Return a value of a model based on the max value of another field of the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a model in Django with two fields: name and meter. I have created a views file, and I want to find and print the name with the biggest meter. The code below find and prints the biggest meter itself which is good, but not what I want. I want to print the name that is related to that meter. Any idea how to do so?

My Views:

```
 def details (request):
  top_meter = Energy_Consuption.objects.aggregate(Max('meter'))
  return render(request,'details.html', {'top_meter':top_meter})
```

(The view is connected to an HTML page.)

My Model:

```
class Energy_Consuption(models.Model):
  name=models.IntegerField()
  meter=models.IntegerField()
  class Meta:
    db_table:'Energy_Consuption'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Energy_Consuption.objects.filter(
    meter=Energy_Consuption.objects.aggregate(Max('meter'))['meter__max']
).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

This will return the list of the names of the `Energy_Consuption` objects that matches the max value. Note that you need filter here, because there can be more than one `Energy_Consuption` with the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the QuerySet by `meter` and take the latest item.
Additionally, you can use `getattr` in case of QuerySet being empty.

```py
biggest_item = EnergyConsumption.objects.latest('meter')
biggest_name = getattr(biggest_item, 'name', None)
```

If your `meter` field is not unique, you can provide additional fields to the `latest` method to disambiguate:

```py
biggest_item = EnergyConsumption.objects.latest('meter', 'id')
```